# Error after executing hex grid script in QGIS 2.6 for Mac

Tags: pyqgis, mac, qgis-2.6

I'm trying to load a script with QGIS, hex grid from layers bound, with a population shapefile (popp.shp in egis sample data folder). After selecting the layer and executing the script it gives me an error.

Where is the problem?

I attach a couple of screenshots.

[image: scrennshot1]

[image: screenshot2]

Comment: Your `cellsize` is large which probably indicates that it's larger than the actual extent of your layer. Do you really need that big a size?

Comment: Hi @Joseph I changed the cellsize but having same problem...

Comment: Can you include which QGIS version you are using please? Also check if the **Processing** plugin is compatible with your QGIS version.

Comment: That is qgis 2.6 for mac